# Android - Fatal Exception Main Error

Tags: java, android, program-entry-point

I had been tasked to modify an application. I confuse error in main. 
Where is error of main ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    String consumerkey = "A";
    String consumersecret = "A";
    String token = "S";
    String tokensecret = "D";

    String nonce = "Vf";
    String signature = "D";
    String signaturemethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
    String timestamp = "2";

    {   
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerkey)
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumersecret)
          .setOAuthAccessToken(token)
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(tokensecret);
    }

    //TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    //Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.

//insert the appropriate consumer key and consumer secret here

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
    nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_name);
    descTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    pageDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pageDescription);
    pageDescription.setText("Timeline");
    // Initialize the pager

    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    this.initialisePagingTimeline();
}
```

Is android main only in OnCreate ? I am newbie for android. If not only OnCreate, It will make me to give very long source code (because full source code is very long so I can't give). Can you help me to solve my problem ?

I can't upload logcat error image because my reputation is still under ten.

Comment: I suggest you to remove your secret keys from the source code, you shouldn't share it.

Comment: What is the error reported in LogCat?

Comment: I have change secret key. The Error is FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN. And I didn't see anything error which relate with main

Comment: I'm sorry I forget this error. Maybe there is relation with this error : "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException". I can't upload image because my reputation still under ten

Comment: You will be getting the Line number of your error..indicate that

Comment: I'm sorry I don't maintenance this question. My problems is solved...all. I was ask to my senior last hour.